# Flutter Utils Guide for beginner

Tags: flutter, user-interface, design-patterns, mobile

do you have any guide about hierarchy of **Utility folder **in Flutter *(padding, string, device, color, enums)*

I saw this video on Youtube about this problem and I want to learn more about Utility concept
[Mastering Flutter: Essential Utilities, Helper Functions, Constants and much more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3StjTeWs-ZQ&t=741s) - Coding With T